# query to check there are registration types with price "> 0"

Tags: laravel

I have a table registration_types that is associated with a conference, a conference can have multiple registration types.

So the registration_types table have columns like: id, name, price, conference_id.

And I want to do a query to check if for a specific conference there are registration types where the price is not free, that is the price is ">0".

I already have the conference id with:

```
    $conference = Conference::where('id',$id)->firstOr(function(){
        return redirect('/');
    });
    $conferenceID = $conference->id;
```

But now do you know how to know if there are registration types where the price is not 0 for that $conferenceID?

Models:

RegistrationType model:

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

Conference model:

```
class Conference extends Model
{
    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

With:

```
$paidConferences = $conference->whereHas("registrationTypes", function($query) use ($conferenceID){
    $query->where('price', '>', '0');
    $query->where('id', '=', $conferenceID);
})->get();
```

The "dd($paidConferences);" shows the conference details like:

```
Collection {#331 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Conference {#330 ▼
      ...
      #attributes: array:22 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "conference test"
        "description" => null
        ...
      ]
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

But what is necessary is that $paidConferences shows the total price of all registration types associated with a conference, so is possible to do a if for example:

```
@if($paidConferences >0)
<!-- show some html -->
@else
<!-- show some other html -->

@endif
```

Comment: You're probably Looking for `->whereHas("registrationTypes", function($query){ ... });`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Something like "$paidConferencesExist = $conference->whereHas("registrationTypes", function($query){
                $query->where('price', '>', '0');
            });"?

Comment: Yup; something like that. Looks correct at a glance; give it a run and see if you get the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, but instead of returning the registration types where price is ">0" to check if there are registration types with price ">0" the $paidConferencesExist shows "Collection {#344 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Conference {#333 ▶}
    1 => Conference {#342 ▶}
    2 => Conference {#345 ▶}
  ]
}"

Comment: Right sorry, you still need the `where("id", "=", $id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for simple scenario, you can get your conference by doing

```
$conference = Conference::find($id);
```

Then, to get all registration types, it's pretty simple, you just have to query your registrationTypes relationship. Let's do it:

```
$conference->registrationTypes()->where('price','>',0)->get();
```

If you find yourself using this query many times and you don't want to repeat yourself, you can make a scope inside your RegistrationType model:

```
public function scopeNotFree($query)
{
    return $query->where('price','>',0);
}
```

Your query will now look like that:

```
$conference->registrationTypes()->notFree()->get();
```

And it's not over yet, depending of your frequency of use of this query, you might also have a registrationTypesNotFree relationship in your Conference model:

```
public function registrationTypesNotFree()
{
    return $this->registrationTypes()->notFree();
}
```

It may be a bit overkill in your case, but there is nothing wrong with it. It all up to you :)

Finally, knowing if the conference has a not free registration type will be as simple as

```
$conference->registrationTypesNotFree()->count();
```

or

```
$conference->registrationTypes()->notFree()->count();
```

or

```
$conference->registrationTypes()->where('price','>',0)->count();
```

These queries will all return you the number of related registration types that are not free.

Comment: Thanks, like that "$conference->registrationTypes()->where('price','>',0)->count();" it returns the number of registration types that are not free. Do you know how to return the sum of the price of all registration types associated with the conference?

Comment: So that is possible to do a if like if the conference is not free (@if($paidConferences >0)) show some html otherwise show other html. A confernece is free if  associated only with  registration types that have a price "=0".

Comment: You can do it by simply doing `$conference->registrationTypes()->sum('price');` :)

Comment: You can check if the conference has at least one not free registration types and do whatever you need to.

`@if($paidConferences > 0) display some html @else display other html @endif`